# Protocol/Convention for methods accepting container types as output parameters

Tags: c++, stl

When you have methods that accept containers as output parameters, whose responsibility is it to clear the list? (if at all)
For example,

```
bool GetResults(int nID, list<string>& results)
{
    .....
}
```

In this case, should the method GetResults clear the list? Or should it assume that the caller knows what he is doing?
If GetResults clears the output list, then it may negate an effort by the caller to collect results across multiple calls,
For example,

```
list<string> results.

GetResults(1,results)

GetResults(17,results)
```

Comment: As a general rule do not use `std::list` as it rarely is a good idea.  An interesting alternative to the above is to return a tuple of bool and vector, and expect the caller to use tie.  Another approach is to take an output iterator and fill it as the caller requests.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to write such methods so they take an output iterator:

```
template <typename OutputIterator>
OutputIterator GetResults(int nID, OutputIterator out)
```

This pushes the decision to clear the results back to the caller.

It pushes the decision on what container to use to hold the results back to the caller as well - no more hard-coding `std::list` in the interface.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is really that it depends what you prefer and then saying what happens in the interface specification and sticking to it.

As long as you don't mix and are being consistent, I don't think it matters who empties the list.